# Alinhar árvore em CSS na vertical

Tags: css, árvore, horizontal

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto onde preciso mostrar uma árvore genealógica. O mais próximo que encontrei foi através [desse tópico](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27825413/vertical-family-tree-in-css3). Porém está exibindo horizontalmente.

Como alterar para que seja exibido verticalmente?

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  min-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 50px;
  color: #000;
  font: 16px Verdana, sans-serif;
  background: #fff;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

#wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.branch {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 250px;
}
.branch:before {
  content: "";
  width: 50px;
  border-top: 2px solid #000;
  position: absolute;
  left: -100px;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: 1px;
}

.entry {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 60px;
}
.entry:before {
  content: "";
  height: 100%;
  border-left: 2px solid #000;
  position: absolute;
  left: -50px;
}
.entry:after {
  content: "";
  width: 50px;
  border-top: 2px solid #000;
  position: absolute;
  left: -50px;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: 1px;
}
.entry:first-child:before {
  width: 10px;
  height: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: 2px;
  border-radius: 10px 0 0 0;
}
.entry:first-child:after {
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px 0 0 0;
}
.entry:last-child:before {
  width: 10px;
  height: 50%;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 10px;
}
.entry:last-child:after {
  height: 10px;
  border-top: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 10px;
  margin-top: -9px;
}
.entry.sole:before {
  display: none;
}
.entry.sole:after {
  width: 50px;
  height: 0;
  margin-top: 1px;
  border-radius: 0;
}

.label {
  display: block;
  min-width: 150px;
  padding: 5px 0px;
  line-height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -15px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper"><span class="label">Root</span>
  <div class="branch lv1">
    <div class="entry"><span class="label">Entry-1</span>
      <div class="branch lv2">
        <div class="entry"><span class="label">Entry-1-1</span>
          <div class="branch lv3">
            <div class="entry sole"><span class="label">Entry-1-1-1</span></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="entry"><span class="label">Entry-1-2</span>
          <div class="branch lv3">
            <div class="entry sole"><span class="label">Entry-1-2-1</span></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="entry"><span class="label">Entry-1-3</span>
          <div class="branch lv3">
            <div class="entry sole"><span class="label">Entry-1-3-1</span></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="entry"><span class="label">Entry-2</span></div>
    <div class="entry"><span class="label">Entry-3</span>
      <div class="branch lv2">
        <div class="entry"><span class="label">Entry-3-1</span></div>
        <div class="entry"><span class="label">Entry-3-2</span></div>
        <div class="entry"><span class="label">Entry-3-3</span>
          <div class="branch lv3">
            <div class="entry"><span class="label">Entry-3-3-1</span></div>
            <div class="entry"><span class="label">Entry-3-3-2</span>
              <div class="branch lv4">
                <div class="entry"><span class="label">Entry-3-3-2-1</span></div>
                <div class="entry"><span class="label">Entry-3-3-2-2</span></div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="entry"><span class="label">Entry-3-3-3</span></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="entry"><span class="label">Entry-3-4</span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="entry"><span class="label">Entry-4</span></div>
    <div class="entry"><span class="label">Entry-5</span></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O seu código é baseado em posicionamentos absolutos e margens relativas à disposição que você tem agora (i.e., a classe `label` fica a `50%` do topo da sua `div` pai, a classe `branch` tem `margin-left: 250px`, e assim por diante). Ou seja, ele foi *feito* para ser mostrado da esquerda pra direita. Se você precisa, necessáriamente, fazer essa conversão, eu vejo dois jeitos de se fazer isso:

1. Fazer a conversão manualmente

   Basicamente, você vai rotacionar o seu código em 90º. Tudo que estiver posicionado com relação à esquerda, deverá ser posicionado com relação ao topo, e assim suscetivamente. É um trabalho meio cansativo, repetitivo, e com grandes chances de fazer com que você se perca. Mas como programadores [não gostam de repetir as coisas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself), você pode apelar para a segunda opção.
2. `transform: rotate()`

   Já que você vai rotacionar tudo no braço, qual é o problema em deixar que o CSS lide com isso? Se você aplicar

   ```
   #wrapper {
       -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
       -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
       -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
       -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
       transform: rotate(90deg);
   }
   ```

   Vai ver que já tem meio caminho andado. O problema é que, nesse caso, você rotaciona tudo que tem dentro de `#wrapper`, incluindo o texto (o que eu suponho que você não quer). Para solucionar tal problema, basta você rotacionar o texto em -90º, ou 270º.

   ```
    span {
       -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
       -moz-transform: rotate(270deg);
       -o-transform: rotate(270deg);
       -ms-transform: rotate(270deg);
       transform: rotate(270deg);
   }
   ```

   Isso resolve quase que 100% do seu problema, e você pode vê-lo funcionando [aqui](http://codepen.io/caio1511/pen/NqXZOw). Note que tive que adicionar `margin-top:200px;` para que a palavra *root* aparecesse. Note também que alguns *overlaps* surgiram entre as palavras. Isso se dá por conta da rotação, e de que o código não foi construído pra esta orientação. Você pode brincar com esta pen agora, e ver como os valores se comportam, depois de aplicada a transformação. O trabalho para remover esses *overlaps* não deve ser muito grande.

A partir daqui, você escolhe que tipo de trabalho vai realizar. Eu, particularmente, recomendo que você reescreva o código (i.e., siga a opção 1). Apesar de repetitivo, cansativo e tudo mais, vale bastante o aprendizado.